# How can i show my subarray unsing Angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

```
  $scope.mainArray = [];

  $scope.subArray = [];

  var myObject = {}

  myObject.task = "write";

  myObject.execute = true;

  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.mainArray.length; i++) {

        $scope.subArray[i] = myObject;
        $scope.mainArray[i] = $scope.subArray;
  }
```

How can i show the elements inside my subArray using angular js? I'm using the directive ng-repeat to show my mainArray like: ng-repeat="elements in mainArray"

Answer (score 0):

As per your JS code each element inside your `mainArray` is basically a `subArray`. In other words, variable `elements` from your `ng-repeat` denotes a `subArray`. You can iterate over it as shown below and use its value to print content in UI

```
<div ng-repeat="subArray in mainArray">
    <div ng-repeat="item in mainArray">
        ... do some stuff with item here
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="subArray in mainArray">
  <div ng-repeat="el in subArray">{{el}}</div>
</div>
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/1998/)

It seems like you have the logic set to make the main array properly